# Handling '0 references' for php callbacks in visuel studiio code when

Tags: php, visual-studio-code, wordpress-plugin-creation, intelephense

When editing wordpress code in Visual Studio Code,
if I have a function definition and than I use it as a callback for a call to `add_action` or `add_filter` like this:

```
function myCallback() {
    //do some stuff
}

add_action('init', 'myCallback') ;
```

but because its used as a string its not counted as a reference to the function and the intelisense says `0 references` above my function which is true to some degree but also false and misleading in the practical sense.

Can I do something to tell visual studio code to add a reference to that function?

I was hoping I maybe could do something like (This is not real working code...):

```
function myCallback() {
    //do some stuff
}

add_action('init', myCallback.name) ;
```

i.e. get the name of myCallbck by referencing a member field or method of it.

or (This is again not a currently working solution - just an idea...)

```
add_action('init','myCallback' /* @references:myCallback */)
```

i.e. by adding some comment that intelephanse could use to understand that there is a reference this it would otherwise miss.

Comment: `add_action('init',myCallback.name) ` - that does not look like valid PHP code

Comment: Are you using builtin PHP support or some third-party extension? The tag you've added to the question is for Visual Studio, which is a different product.

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález to be honest, I am not sure, I think I had both. now I turned off the built in one.  which tag are you referring to? I have visual-studio-code  (or maybe someone edited it?

Comment: "IntelliSense is Microsoft's implementation of automatic [code-completion], best known for its use in the Microsoft Visual Studio integrated development environment". The names are intentionally confusing, but Visual Studio Code is not the same as Visual Studio, Microsoft ships two vastly different IDEs. What do you mean with having both? Aside from builtin PHP support, there're at least three major third-party PHP extensions. You have to install them on purpose, they don't come pre-installed.

Comment: Just saw you clarify that in a comment under an answer, I've fixed question tags.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using PHP 8.1, you can use the [first class callable syntax](https://www.php.net/manual/en/functions.first_class_callable_syntax.php)

```
add_action('init', myCallback(...));
```

---

I tried DEVSENSE's PHP extension, the following callable form can be recognized as a reference.

```
class Foo {
    public static function myCallback() {}
}

add_action('init', [Foo::class, 'myCallback']);
```

Comment: This looks interesting. unfortunately at the current time my site is running PHP 8.0.3.

Comment: Are you using DEVSENSE's PHP extension for code lens? If so, try to define the callback as a static method, then you can use `[Foo::class, 'bar']`, the extension will recognize it as a reference.

Comment: no, I am using  PHP Intelephense.

Comment: I've just tested this with PHP Intelephense and it works like a charm (assuming we're talking about the "Peek references" command).

Answer (score 1):

You can use a callback to assign your function to:

```
$callable = function() {
   echo 'Hello world!';
};

call_user_func($callable);
```

The variable `$callable` has the type callable, and
[call_user_func](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.call-user-func.php) has an argument of the type `callable`, just like [add_action](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_action/).

You can use that like so:

```
add_action('init', $callable);
```

This works for several versions: https://3v4l.org/1tH3K
If I read 3v4l.org right, it works for

> 5.3.0 - 5.3.29, 5.4.0 - 5.4.45, 5.5.0 - 5.5.38, 5.6.0 - 5.6.40, 7.0.0 - 7.0.33, 7.1.0 - 7.1.33, 7.2.0 - 7.2.34, 7.3.0 - 7.3.33, 7.4.0 - 7.4.33, 8.0.0 - 8.0.30, 8.1.0 - 8.1.23, 8.2.0 - 8.2.10

Comment: I understand that instead of defining the function, you assign an anonymous function to a variable here.

how would this work with a call to add_action ? 

also i like 3v4l.org which I was not familiar with.

Comment: Well, the variable is of the type "callable", which add_actions needs If i see it correctly in the docs. So you'd just put it in the second argument. I'll add it to the answer. (the reason i choose to use `call_user_func` was that it is easy testable without wordpress)

Comment: The way this works with PHP Intelephense is that it will find references to the variable itself rather than the function. Also, this requires that `$callable` in available in the scope where `add_action()` is called (I've no idea how WordPress works) and that PHP Intelephense recognises variables across files (I don't know). I can't think of better solutions for PHP/8.0 and plain function callbacks.

Comment: Yes, that is indeed an option. It does require some sort of heuristics from your IDE though, which could also work for the question itself. This alternative does indeed have drawbacks, forcing you to be more explicit and throwing the variable around, but it is another option that might help for a specific usecase where the heuristicis/intellisense/whatever is not finding your string a 'usage'